# How to change color of link and icon when isActive?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, colors, icons

I have `icon` inside `Link` tag in my React component. I would like when **Link is active** **to change the color of icon also**. According to the code written below, when the link is active, the color of the icon also changes. But when I set the color of the icon in its css, the color of the icon no longer changes when the link is active. How would I change that?

```
 const prop = ({ path, icon, isActive }) => (
 <Link to={path} className={`nav-link ${isActive ? "active-link" : ""}`}>
   <i className={`${icon} customIcon `}></i>
   <span>{text}</span>
 </Link>
 )
```

This is css code:

```
.nav-link {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;

  color: #52575c;
}

.customIcon {
  width: 18px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 6px;
 /* color: #52575c; */
}

.active-link {
  color: #336cfb;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Icon className ${icon} is applying the color, adding a new line for customIcon classname with the active-link class prefix should work.

```
.nav-link {
  ....
}

.customIcon {
  ...
}

.active-link,
.active-link .customIcon {
  color: #336cfb;
}
```

Keep the current className order `${icon} customIcon`

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways to approach this, one method I would try is nesting the color of the icon underneath the nav-link like this:

```
.nav-link.active-link {
 color: #000; /* color when the nav-link is active */
}
.nav-link.active-link i {
 color: #000; /* color of the icon when the parent nav-link is active */
}
```

Worst case, if you can't figure out another way to do this, you can override CSS specificity using the `!important` operator like this:

```
color: #000 !important; /* value that should really be set */
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have class for your color and use it like this

```
const prop = ({ path, icon, isActive }) => (
 <Link to={path} className={`nav-link ${isActive ? "active-link" : "not-active"}`}>
   <i className={`${icon} customIcon `}></i>
   <span>{text}</span>
 </Link>
 )
```

CSS

```
.active-link {
  color: #336cfb;
}
.not-active {
  color: #52575c;
}
```

remove the color property on `.nav-link` class

you can use NavLink instead of the link, which gives you a callback function on the className prop that you can access the activity of link like this

```
       <NavLink
       to="/"
       className={(link) => (link.isActive ? "active-nav-link" : "")
       }
       link
       </NavLink>
```